Anomaly in variable separation of 1D Schrodinger Wave Equation
I'll be following the book titled "Solid State Electronic Devices", 7th edition, by Ben G. Streetman and Sanjay K. Banerjee.
The derivation starts with looking at the energy balance equation of a classical particle:
$$\frac{1}{2m}p^2 + V = E$$
The terms mean: Kinetic Energy, Potential Energy and finally, Total Energy (Respectively).
The book states (Page 43) the following quantum mechanical operators:

This yields:
$$-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi(x,t)}{\partial x^2} + V(x)\Psi(x,t) = -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{\partial\Psi(x,t)}{\partial t}$$
Clever move: $V(x)$ does not depend on time $t$.
Applying the method of separation of variables: $\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)\phi(t)$
This yields, upon simplification:
$$-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{1}{\psi(x)}\frac{d^2\psi(x)}{d x^2} + V(x) = -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{1}{\phi(t)}\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} = E$$
Since both sides of the equation depend on entirely different variables, they must be constants, equal to $E$ the total energy.
Now, this is where my problem arises.
We converted the $E$ from the classical particle energy equation as:
$$ E  = -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{\partial\Psi(x,t)}{\partial t}$$
We later figured out that:
$$E =  -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{1}{\phi(t)}\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}$$
Where $$\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)\phi(t) $$
We conclude that:
$$-\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{\partial\Psi(x,t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{1}{\phi(t)}\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}$$
Which gives us the erratic equation:
$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\psi(t)}$$
Which yields..
$$\Psi(x,t) = 1$$
This does not make sense. Where have I gone wrong?

Just to expand on @BioPhycisict's answer: An equation like $E = \frac{-h}{j} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}$ cannot be right if you want to interpret $E$ as a number, because the right-hand side is clearly a function of time, and not just a number.
The correct equation is $H \Psi = \frac{-h}{j} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}$ (the Schrödinger equation), where we have now (1) written $H$ instead of $E$, because $H$ is the operator associated with the observable energy, and (2) let the operator act on the wave function, such that $\Psi$ now appears on both sides of the equation.
Now if $\Psi$ is an eigenstate of $H$ with energy $E$, we can indeed write
$$ E \Psi = \frac{-h}{j} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t},$$
where $E$ is a number. Following now what you have done, we find that
$$ E  = \frac{-h}{j} \frac{1}{\Psi} \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}
= \frac{-h}{j} \frac{1}{\phi} \frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d} t},$$
which is consistent.

Looks like the book I followed used $E$ for both the operator and the number? Am I correct?

Maybe, but that is not totally clear to me. Note that  classically both energy and momentum are just numbers; therefore when you convert a classical equation to a quantum equation you replace a number by an operator, e.g. $E \rightarrow H$, or $p \rightarrow -j\hbar \nabla$. Notice that the table you listed from the book does not put an equality sign between $E$ and $-j \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, which would be wrong! It is rather a prescription for a procedure on how to convert a classical equation to a quantum one

The problem is here:

$$ E  = -\frac{\hbar}{j}\frac{\partial\Psi(x,t)}{\partial t}$$

While the part on the right is related to energy, it is not equal to $E$. This equation is not used in your derivation.

1.If the term is not equal to $E$, what is it exactly?
2.I realize the equation is not used in the derivation. I wrongly framed the title of my question. The derivation is fine, but I have problems later on when the method of separation of variables is performed. My bad.

@McSuperbX1 Really the importance of that time derivative is the whole point of the Schrodinger equation. It relates that time derivative of the wave function to the spatial derivatives.
